# Newpagestyle always starts a new page

Tags: formatting, page-breaking

is there any option to prevent Latex from starting a new page when I change the pagestyle (\pagestyle{...})?

**Related to this question. Whenever I start a new chapter I get the page number in "1" on the first page of this chapter, while I defined it in the pagestyle to be "-1-", but after the first page it works as defined.**

In the following code you see both errors at once. The first page has the "1" numbering. Additionally, after \pagestyle{standard_begin} the line a new page begins.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} % header and footer
  \usepackage{titlesec}
  \usepackage[left=2.4cm,right=3.8cm,top=1in,bottom=1.2in]{geometry}

\fancypagestyle{standard_begin}{%
%  \fancyhf{\thepage}
\newgeometry{top=5cm}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.0pt}
    \fancyhead{}
  \fancyfoot[CE,CO]{\footnotesize $-\;$\thepage $\;-$ }
}

\fancypagestyle{standard_intro}{%
%  \fancyhf{\thepage}
\newgeometry{top=1in}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
    \fancyhead[LE]{}
    \fancyhead[RE]{\scriptsize\textbf{\RUNTITLE}\\\ Introduction}
    \fancyhead[RO]{\scriptsize\textbf{\RUNTITLE}\\\ Introduction}
    \fancyhead[LO]{}
  \fancyfoot[CE,CO]{\footnotesize $-\;$\thepage $\;-$ }
}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{standard_intro}
\chapter{blab}
text text 
\pagestyle{standard_begin}
Text TextTextTextTextText
\end{document}
```

Any ideas here?

Thank you so much

Comment: Where does `\newpagestyle` come from? As always on this site, please provide a full (but minimal) example that others can copy and test as is.

Comment: Chapter pages uses pagestyle `plain` by default.

Comment: `\newgeometry` changes the page layout. Therefore it starts a new page. Do not use `\newgeometry` in the pagestyle settings.

Comment: Thank you esdd. This helped with the jumping pages. Do you also know how I get the numbering shown in the correct way, that is, "-1-" instead of "1"?

Comment: Define a fancypagestyle `plain`, eg. `\fancypagestyle{plain}{\fancyhf{}\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}\fancyfoot[C]{\footnotesize $-\;$\thepage $\;-$ }}`

Comment: \If you use `\pagestyle` on a page twice, the second style "wins". But if there are also a `\thispagestyle` command on a page, this style will be used. Note that `\chapter` executes `\thispagestyle{plain}`. Maybe you have to discribe what should be on which page in header and footer.

Comment: Thank you all for your input!